# tag count unevenness among website and android app

Tags: bug, tags

Apparently, since some day I have a tag count unevenness between what I can see on the website and what I can see in the adroid app (which looks like 10% outdated on avg.).

Is this an expected behavior?

E.g.

my matlab tag counts 201 on the website and 224 on the app; Python counts as 33 vs. 45.

Comment: Take a look at this answer on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315/215013.